# Stack и Heap в Java

Tags: java, jvm

Здравствуйте , подскажите пожалуйста . В Java есть несколько областей памяти Heap , Stack & Permanent Generation. Вот мы начинаем с метода main. Вызываем у него какие-то методы .
У них есть локальные переменные и ссылки, которые хранятся в стеке . Все хорошо. Но допустим мы создаем новый инстанс класса внутри метода . `MyClass obj = new MyClass();`
Но у этого класса есть свои методы , переменные (члены класса) примитивного типа. 
Допустим

```
class MyClass {
int x ;
float y;
MyClass inObj; 
}
```

И также присутствуют ссылки на объекты другие ( в данном случае на объект такого же класса ). 
Собственно вопрос. Где будут храниться локальные переменные и ссылки класса выделенного из main. В Heap или Stack ? 
Спасибо .

Comment: @Alexandr Crospov эмм... а зачем такие тонкости знать простому девелоперу? Я бы понял, если бы вы писали компилятор или там что-то служебное для оси

Comment: @Barmaley, согласитесь, простому девелоперу полезно знать, откуда растут ноги у OutOfMemoryError, и почему часть из них просит Java heap, а другая - PermGen.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понимаю (знатоки Java пусть меня поправят), всё, что выделено при помощи `new`, лежит в heap-памяти. В частности, экземпляры классов тоже лежат в heap, вместе со всеми своими полями.

У класса самого по себе нету локальных переменных. Локальные переменные есть у его методов, эти переменные размещаются в стеке, когда метод вызывается.

Возможные отклонения от этой схемы (они реализованы в C#, не знаю, так ли в Java):

- Если оптимизатор может доказать, что экземпляр класса не покидает пределов метода, он может переместить его в стек невидимым для программиста образом для эффективности
- Не знаю, имеет ли право компилятор неявно перемещать в heap локальные переменные, захваченные лямбда-функцией.

Comment: По второму пункту: создаёт копию значений захваченных локальных переменных.

Comment: @AlexeyM: Хм, значит, захватывать можно только `final`?

Comment: В Java <= 7. Начиная с Java 8 вводится понятие effective final, т.е. в которые не производится запись.

Comment: @AlexeyM: Круто, не знал. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Ссылка на класс на стеке, сам экземпляр класса в heap'е. Кроме того, при включенном флаге `-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis` и ключом `-server` JVM может размещать экземпляры классов на стеке, если на эти экземпляры нет ссылок за пределами блока (при этом оптимизируемый таким образом метод должен сначала откомпилироваться JIT). См. [EscapeAnalysis](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/EscapeAnalysis).

Comment: @a_gura: формально, ссылка может попасть в heap, если она — поле другого класса. Я бы делал разделение по критерию поле/локальная переменная.

Comment: @VladD если ссылка - это поле другого класса, она всегда в heap'е (в рамках самого класса), если только это не локальная копия ссылки или не сработал escape analysis для содержащего ее класса.

Answer (score 2):

**Стэк/Stack**  - находится в оперативной памяти (RAM) хранит ссылки на объекты, а также примитивы.
**Куча/Heap** (также в RAM) - хранит все объекты (не ссылки).
**Permanent generation** используется только JVM для хранения необходимых данных, в том числе метаданные о созданных объектах.
**Постоянное хранилище** (ROM) - хранит строковые литералы и константы.
**Внешнее хранилище** - хранит потоковые объекты (поток в виде байтов) и долгоживущие (persistent) объекты (сохраняют свое состояние после закрытия программы)