# Чем переменная класса отличается от экземпляра класса?

Tags: java

Например, у нас есть класс `MyClass`.

Чем вот эта запись

```
MyClass class = new MyClass();
```

отличается от этой

```
MyClass class;
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82+%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0

Comment: 1) MyClass class; - Вы создали ссылку типа MyClass в стеке, но она пока ни на что не указывает. 2) MyClass class = new MyClass(); - теперь вы создали в куче новый объект и привязали его к ссылке class

Comment: я переименовал вопрос так, чтобы заголовок начал соответствовать содержимому.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
```

1. Вы объявляете переменную или поле `myClass` типа `MyClass`.
2. Создаете новый экземпляр (объект) класса `MyClass`.
3. Присваиваете ссылку на созданный экземпляр переменной.

---

```
MyClass myClass;
```

1. Вы объявляете переменную или поле `myClass` типа `MyClass`. Переменная не инициализирована никаким значением, работать с ней нельзя, пока вы не присвоите ей ссылку на какой-нибудь экземпляр.

Answer (score 0):

Для более эффективного использования памяти, в Java используются так называемые пулы. Есть строковый пул, Integer pool и тд. 
Вот пример кода:

```
Integer a = 120;
Integer b = 120;
Integer c = 130;
Integer d = 130;
Integer e = 127;
Integer f = 127;


System.out.println("a==b :" + (a==b)); // true , cравнение двух ссылок на объект но объект не создавался
System.out.println("c==d :"+ (c==d) ); // false, мы вышли за границы 
System.out.println("e==f :" + (e==f) ); // true
```

Что вам еще пригодится: "Разница между Stack и Heap памятью в Java"
Вот на stackoverflow [запись >>>](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/325000/stack-%D0%B8-heap-%D0%B2-java)