# Как работает выделение памяти в Java?

Tags: java, память

Я только начинаю учить джаву, и мне непонятны некоторые моменты. Я прочитал что большинство переменных хранится в куче и в связи с этим возникли такие вопросы:

Что хранится в стеке?
Могу ли я использовать память в стеке для своих переменных и объектов класса?
Получается если я создаю обычную целочисленную переменную, то она хранится в куче и я обращаюсь к ней по ссылке?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: [Stack Memory and Heap Space in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stack-heap)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Stack и Heap в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/325000/stack-%d0%b8-heap-%d0%b2-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрим в спеку: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5

- В кучу складываются экземпляры классов и массивы.
- Локальные переменные хранятся в стеке.

В джаве нет понятия "обычная" переменная. Если Вы имеете в виду поле класса то да, само значение будет храниться в куче, а обращаться к нему Вы будете через ссылку на объект. Если же имеется в виду локальная переменная примитивного типа, то она полностью будет храниться в стеке. Сложить в стек объекты нельзя, т.к. только ссылки будут складываться в стек, а сами объекты будут храниться в куче.